# Dispose a object been added to a collection, but the collection still has reference to it

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, dispose, using

Read some code from a legecy system.

Say I have a instance of class A, then added it to a collection, then dispose it.

I just can not understand what's the point to use implicit dispose here since the code still use the myControlCollcetion,which means the cltCheckBoxA  wont be really freed anyway.

Why?

```
using (UserControlA cltCheckBoxA = new UserControlA())
{
    //some operation
    base.myControlCollcetion.Add(cltCheckBoxA);
}

//Other operation against myControlCollcetion
```

Comment: It's just a bug.  Easy to never see it in practice because disposing the control will remove it from the collection again.

Comment: @HansPassant No, disposing it won't remove it from the collection.

Comment: think it wont remove the object, but just leaves the Control in an unusable state. Because the system is working properly even with this buggy code.

Comment: Depends on what myControlCollcetion actually is and how Ownership is setup here. The question lacks a lot of detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disposing an object is entirely different from freeing it's managed memory (which is what the GC does).  Dispose is explicitly cleaning up all *unmanaged* resources that the garbage collector can't free.

This means that when the object is used after `Dispose` is called on it there are a lot of possibilities.  (This is not an exhaustive list.)

1. Many objects are essentially unusable once their unmanaged resources are cleaned up.  In this case, it's common for them to throw an exception whenever one of their members is accessed.
2. The object could just act in an unexpected manor because it is being used after it is disposed.  It might result in weird exceptions, or just incorrect results from methods, or, really, anything.
3. It may never have actually had unmanaged resources.  Some objects implement IDisposable just so that they are more extensible, or to try to future-proof them.  `DataTable` is an example of this; it's `Dispose` does nothing.  In this case, the object will work just fine after it is disposed.
4. It's possible that the object is still usable even without its unmanaged resources.  Maybe only a portion of it's functionality becomes unusable after `Dispose` is called, in which case as long as only those limited aspects are used later on it will work just fine.
5. Some object might re-create it's unmanaged resources when accessed after it is disposed.  It would be bad practice, but it's your class you can do what you want.

Comment: Ok, get your point, the obejct may still can be used even after the dispose (unstable object then), but the code is a bad practice anyway.

Comment: @ValidfroM That is the purpose of the method/interface and most certainly how it should be used.  In actual practice, nothing stops you from violating that.  Clearly it is being violated here, the only question is whether that violation will result in it just throwing an exception, or if the program will work despite violating best practices.

Comment: @Servy: In some cases, an object might implement have a `Close` method which frees all its resources, but allows the use of some properties which might have to be used after a `Close` (e.g. a connection's "total bytes transferred" property).  If `Close` would clean up all the resources, I wouldn't see any need to make a `Dispose` method invalidate properties which `Close` deliberately left usable.  IMHO, objects should throw `ObjectDisposedException` when the alternative would be #2 or #5 above, but I would consider #1, #3, and #4 to be equally valid.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, there is no reason of doing this, and even if there is, this is bad code, very confusing.

The *developer* may intend to call esplicitly `Dispose(..)` on  the `UserControlA` (for some reason. For example in the code section marked with `//some operation` may be executed some function that allocated unmanaged resources), and tried to do that avoid adding additional `try/catch` sequence (`using` handles that automatically).

But I repeat this is *not* a good code.